# Get LUIS training evaluation metrics & result using API

Tags: azure, api, azure-language-understanding

I'm developing a solution that integrates with LUIS using API calls.

I can't find the API to get information from the Dashboard as for example incorrect predictions and unclear predictions. So far I found just this API:

`{ENDPOINT}/luis/webapi/v2.0/apps/{APP_ID}/versions/{VERSION}/statsmetadata`

but this is not enough, since I would get more detailed information like the one displayed in the dashboard:

[image: stats]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `statsmetadata` endpoint is the right operation for displaying the figures for the pie chart.

## Sample

Here is an example in one of my LUIS apps

### Dashboard display

The dashboard gives the following details:
[image: Dashboard]

### Data origin

StatsMetadata endpoint gives all the details. Here is the call that is made: `https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com//luis/webApi/v2.0/apps/*MyAppId*/versions/*MyAppVersion*/statsmetadata`

JSON Result:

```
{
    "appVersionUtterancesCount": 8505,
    "modelsMetadata": [{
        "modelId": "IdOfModel1,
        "modelName": "modelName1",
        "utterancesCount": 85,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 7,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 19,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 7
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel2",
        "modelName": "modelName2",
        "utterancesCount": 402,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 11,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 32,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 11
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel3",
        "modelName": "modelName3",
        "utterancesCount": 293,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 9,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 42,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 9
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel4",
        "modelName": "modelName4",
        "utterancesCount": 58,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 3,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 5,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 3
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel5",
        "modelName": "modelName5",
        "utterancesCount": 943,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 7,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 103,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 7
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel6",
        "modelName": "modelName6",
        "utterancesCount": 266,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 9,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 70,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 9
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel7",
        "modelName": "modelName7",
        "utterancesCount": 2441,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 68,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 180,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 67
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel8",
        "modelName": "modelName8",
        "utterancesCount": 704,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 40,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 154,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 40
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel9",
        "modelName": "modelName9",
        "utterancesCount": 288,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 9,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 65,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 9
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel10",
        "modelName": "modelName10",
        "utterancesCount": 18,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 1,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 1,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 1
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel11",
        "modelName": "modelName11",
        "utterancesCount": 444,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 12,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 50,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 12
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel12",
        "modelName": "modelName12",
        "utterancesCount": 10,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 8,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 8,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 8
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel13",
        "modelName": "modelName13",
        "utterancesCount": 58,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 9,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 21,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 9
    }, {
        "modelId": "IdOfModel14",
        "modelName": "None",
        "utterancesCount": 2495,
        "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 194,
        "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 428,
        "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 178
    }],
    "intentsCount": 14,
    "entitiesCount": 7,
    "phraseListsCount": 7,
    "patternsCount": 0,
    "trainingTime": "00:00:53.2732860",
    "lastTrainDate": "2019-10-22T13:25:03Z",
    "misclassifiedUtterancesCount": 387,
    "ambiguousUtterancesCount": 1178,
    "misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount": 370
}
```

### Calculation on API data - Pie Chart

#### Incorrect predictions

Here it is the number of misclassified utterances divided by the total number of utterances

- Formula: `misclassifiedUtterancesCount / appVersionUtterancesCount`
- Check: 387 / 8505 = 0.04550 = 4.6%

#### Unclear predictions

Here it is the number of ambiguous (but not misclassified ambiguous as they are already counted in incorrect predictions) utterances divided by the total number of utterances

- Formula: `(ambiguousUtterancesCount - misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount) / appVersionUtterancesCount`
- Check: (1178 - 370) / 8505 = 808 / 8505 = 0.09500 = 9.5%

#### Correct predictions

It is... what remains! So:
Formula: `(appVersionUtterancesCount - misclassifiedUtterancesCount - (ambiguousUtterancesCount - misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount)) / appVersionUtterancesCount`
Check: (8505 - 387 - (1178 - 370)) / 8505 = (8505 - 387 - 808) / 8505 = 7310 / 8505 = 0.8594 = 85.9%

### Calculation on API data - Right panel details

#### Data Imbalance

It is the models that have the biggest number of `utterancesCount`, but I don't know if there is a threshold ratio used to keep only the top N models

#### Incorrect predictions

By model, check the following ratio: `misclassifiedUtterancesCount / utterancesCount` and keep the ones having the highest ratio.

#### Unclear predictions

By model, check the following ratio: `(ambiguousUtterancesCount - misclassifiedAmbiguousUtterancesCount) / utterancesCount` and keep the ones having the highest ratio.

### Details

You can directly check in your navigator developer tools that LUIS portal is calling this endpoint before displaying the dashboard.